# My Map Wont Grow

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am playing on a LAN minecraft and after a while needed a map, but when I went to make the bigger to see more, it only increased once, no matter how many times I went to make it. Is this a glitch or just a new map size or what? I have tried making a new one and it suffers from the same problem.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're trying to enlarge the map with the recipe of map in the middle and 8 sheets of paper around?

Comment: correct. I have used quite a lot of paper up this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're not shift clicking it out of your inventory, it won't expand the size if you do that. Also, you have to re-explore all the existing territory when you increase the size of a map, so you might as well make it as large as you'll want and then explore.

Answer (score -3):

No, it's not a bug. You need to move a long way away from your first map, till you're on the edge of it, then make a new one.